# Detect lines in Python OpenCV without applying Gaussian Blur

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I am detecting lines in a noiseless, programmatically generated png file. I would normally use Hough Lines, which requires me to first provide edges from a canny detection, but the first step of the canny detection is to apply a gaussian blur to eliminate noise. Is there a way I can do edge detection on my original image without ever intentionally blurring it? I suspect this will yield better results than burring first since the lines are already perfectly clean and high-contrast.

Here is a simple example using canny detection and an image. The lines in each group start at 5 pixels wide, then the next line is 4, then 3, 2, and 1. As you can see, the canny detection doesn't work perfectly (the 2 pixel lines appear smaller than the 1 pixel ones):

Original image:

[image]

Edges (Result of canny detection):

[image]

Sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plot

# img = cv2.imread("8px_and_2px_lines.png")
img = cv2.imread("5-1px_lines.png")

crop_size = 520
img = img[100:crop_size, 100:crop_size]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite("5-1px_lines_cropped.png", img)
cv2.imshow("start", img)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
cv2.imshow("canny", edges)
cv2.imwrite("5-1px_lines_cropped_canny.png", edges)
# plot.imshow(edges, cmap="gray")
# plot.show()

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)
line_length = 3000
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    x1 = int(x0 + line_length * (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + line_length * (a))
    x2 = int(x0 - line_length * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - line_length * (a))
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("lines", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Any ideas on how I can do a better line detection on these images? I think the gaussian blur built into the canny detector is making the lines harder to detect.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your results. You get a Canny edge and Hough line on both sides of each of your thick lines.

Comment: @fmw42 what is confusing me is why the two pixel width line only gets one edge, and the one pixel line still gets two

Comment: Interesting question! Look at the Canny edge image and see if it shows one or two

Comment: @fmw42 I'll update my answer, the image I provided is actually the canny image.

Comment: I believe the answer has to do with the gradient operator and how it overlaps the edges as it shifts across the edge. For example take a vertical (1,0,-1) kernel and shift it vertically one pixel at a time over a 1 row edge of values 1 on a background of value 0 and do the correlation multiplication and addition. You will see there are 3 values that result of -1, 0 and 1. Any non-zero value becomes an edge. So you have 2 edge separated by a black 0 space. With a 2-pixel edge, you get 5 non-zero values in sequence with no spaces. This gets thinned by the non-maximum suppression to one line.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is simply to threshold, invert so lines are white and then skeletonize. Here is code for Python/OpenCV/Skimage

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

img = cv2.imread("lines_horizontal.png")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert so lines are white
thresh = 1 - thresh

# apply skeletonization
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(thresh)
skeleton = (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("lines_horizontal_skeleton.png", skeleton)

# show results
cv2.imshow("skeleton", skeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Note that there will be some distortion right at the ends from the skeletonization at endpoints.

Note also that OpenCV opencv-contrib-python has a thinning method that is similar to skeletonization.